# What is the difference between @Input() and @Input() get and set in angular 4?

Tags: angular

Could you please tell me the difference between @Input() and @Input() get and set and what is the usage of this in angular 5?

```
@Input() value: string;
```

and

```
_value: string;
@Input() set value(value: string) {
   this._value = value;
}
get value(): string {
   return this._value;
}
```

Comment: You can find explanation for the @Input() set usage here: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#intercept-input-property-changes-with-a-setter

Comment: When you want to do something when a value change (and along the life of the application, this happens not only at first) -e.g. you want to make a call to a service based upon this value-, you must use get and set. If only happends at init or this value is only for show it, you needn't use get and set